# Matlab: Solving Symbolic System of Linear Equations with Interpolation functions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, equation-solving, symbolic-computation

I've been trying to solve a system of linear equations, with some variables being interpolated functions of other variables. I've tried turning these functions into symbolic functions, but that doesn't seem to work.  Does anybody have a workaround that **doesn't involve curve-fitting the data**? I would really like to keep my original dataset for accuracy. My dataset is too large to put the real one in this code example, so I've supplied a placeholder dataset of [0 100],[100 0],[0 100;0 100].

Here is my code:

```
%  Setting up system of equations
syms FD ICE EM GEN
AM = [0 1 1 0 ;
0 1 0 0 ;
0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 1];

Tvec = [FD;ICE;EM;GEN]

eqs=  AM * Tvec  ==   Tvec %System of symbolic equations

% Adding the givens to my system of equations
eqs(5) = FD==1;
eqs(6) = ICE==4;
eqs(7) = interp2([0 100],[100 0],[0 100;0 100], ICE,EM)  % <-- this is where the problem is.  

results=solve(eqs)
```

Comment: The first column of AM is zero?? eqs = [0;1;1;1;0;0]??

Comment: First, you seem to be putting symbolic functions/variables (`ICE`,`EM`) into a numeric function (`interp2`). What doesn't work? Is there an error? If so, what? Is that answer wrong? If so, what do you expect?

Comment: @francesco:  The first column of AM is zero, yes.  This results in the equations:
eqs =
 
 EM + ICE == FD
     ICE == ICE
       EM == EM
     GEN == GEN

I know the last 3 equations are redundant, but for my application, using the symbolic solver will automatically remove those equations.

Comment: @horchler:  The error I get when entering eq(7) is:

Error using griddedInterpolant/subsref
Invalid arguments specified in evaluating the interpolant.

Error in interp2 (line 153)
    Vq = F(Xq,Yq);

It seems to not be able to take symbolics as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your system is just an example, but it can be solved trivially by inspection without the use of `solve`. You might try writing out what it represents on paper or doing just  this:

```
syms FD ICE EM GEN
AM = [0 1 1 0
      0 1 0 0
      0 0 1 0
      0 0 0 1];
Tvec = [FD;ICE;EM;GEN]
eqs =  AM*Tvec == Tvec
```

returns

```
eqs =

EM + ICE == FD
    ICE == ICE
      EM == EM
    GEN == GEN
```

The last three equations should look pretty silly to you as they provide no information. You specified in your fifth and sixth equations that `FD == 1` and `ICE == 4`. These aren't trivial at least. Indeed, along with your first equation, `EM + ICE == FD`, you can use them to solve for the fact that `EM == -3`.

Next, your seventh equation isn't even an equation as there's no `==` anywhere. Additionally, as you discovered, `interp2` doesn't accept symbolic inputs. This is true of many Matlab functions. Generally, if you don't see `sym/thefuncname` listed at the bottom when you get help for a function `funcname`, then that function doesn't have a version for symbolic math (or you can directly search `help sym/funcname`). If you want to evaluate the `interp2` line, it appears that you have all of the necessary values:

```
 interp2([0 100],[100 0],[0 100;0 100],4,-3)
```

which returns `NaN` indicating that it used extrapolation (see the help/[documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html#btyra3u-1)).

All in all, I can't figure out what you're trying to do or why you're using interpolation. I'd suggest reading up more on the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-symbolic-math-toolbox.html) and and figuring out what your problem really is.

Comment: thanks for the tips on symbolic math.  For background: I'm trying to solve a topology optimization problem where the equations different based on the entries of AM.  The values of AM will change, and thus will change the equations.  Some of the values are based on interpolated data, and I would like to solve all of the equations simultaneously.

Comment: @teh_allchemist: The main question is whether you need to use symbolic math at all to solve your problem. If this is for optimization, I'd definitely investigate how you can solve your problem numerically. Or perform this in two steps: evaluate your symbolic system to solve for equations that can be used to determine numeric values (use `subs` and `double` to plug in values and confer the output back to floating-point) that can be passed to your optimization.